# Trying to sort an angular-datatable but nothing happens when I click sort

Tags: angular, datatable

Trying to sort this table but nothing happens when I click sort.

If I move *ngFor into the tr tag, the data disappears when I click sort.

Here's the table I'm using:
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <h4>Driver's List</h4>
          <table datatable id="driverTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Distance</th>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">View Info</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let driver of googleDrivers">
              <tr>
                <td>{{driver.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{driver.Distance}}</td>
                <td>{{driver.Duration}}</td>
                <td>Some button</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h4>Directions:</h4>
          <div #map id="gmap" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you recreate the issue on stackblitz? that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your issue I assume your `googleDrivers` list is fetched asynchronously (please provide further code insights if not). If this is the case you have to use a `dtTrigger`, which simply notifies the table to render after your data fetch. You can do this by simply calling  finished by calling `next()`. See in the [docs](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way)

In addition you have to **use the `*ngFor` on the `<tr>` tag**.

Example template:

```
<table datatable id="driverTable" class="table table-striped" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Distance</th>
    <th scope="col">Time</th>
    <th scope="col">View Info</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let driver of googleDrivers">
    <td>{{driver.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{driver.Distance}}</td>
    <td>{{driver.Duration}}</td>
    <td>Some button</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A minimal async data load example in your component code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public googleDrivers: any[] = [];
  public dtTrigger: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData().then(data => {
      this.googleDrivers = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next(); // call trigger next() after data loaded
    });
  }
}
```